# Presentation of Alternating group of order n

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

The presentation  $$\langle s_3,\dots, s_n|s_i^3=1, (s_is_j)^2=1, 3\le i\neq j\le n\rangle$$ is valid for alternating groups of order $n$. I have to prove this. (This is Exercise 7.2 of [Oleg Bogopolski's book *Introduction to group theory*](http://dec1.sinp.msu.ru/~panov/LibBooks/GROUPS/Oleg_Bogopolski-Introduction_to_Group_Theory_%28EMS_Textbooks_in_Mathematics%29-European_Mathematical_Society%282008%29.pdf), on its page 64.)

One approach suggested in the text is 
$ s_i\to (1 2 i)$.

I am unable to establish that it is a presentation by this method.

Can there be a way to establish equivalence with a standard presentation?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: An educated guess would be to [use this presentation for $S_n$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group_on_a_finite_set_is_a_Coxeter_group); that is, to make use of the fact that $S_n$ is a Coxeter group. I'm not sure though. That might be like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @Harunrashid Have you tried mimicking the proof of Theorem 7.1 (on $S_n$) for $A_n$? (Also, it is pages 74-75 of the pdf, but pages 63-64 of the book.)

Comment: Also, I don't understand the downvotes and closure here. The OP is responding to questions and has told us where the question came from (which I feel is suitable context here). Also, its worth pointing out that this is a *hard* question. Proving that a presentation defines a group is, in general, *very* tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect you are intended to mimic the proof of Theorem 7.1, which states that the standard Coxeter presentation of $S_n$ on $n-1$ generators really does present $S_n$.

Lets call the group defined by the presentation $G_n$. The assignment $s_i \mapsto (1,2,i)$ extends to a homomorphism $G \to A_n$, which is surjective, so $|G_n| \ge |A_n|$, and we just need to prove that $|A_n| \le |G_n|$.

We do that by induction on $n$, and the base case $n=3$ is easy.

For $n>3$, define $H$ to be the subgroup $\langle s_3, s_4,\ldots, s_{n-1} \rangle$ of $G_n$. Then, by induction, $|H| \le |A_{n-1}|$, so we need to prove that $|G_n:H| \le n$.

For that, we need to guess $n$ (right) coset representatives of $H$ in $G_n$, and then prove that the guess is correct. Note that the image of $H$ under the homomorphism is the stabilizer of $n$ in $A_n$. The trick in making the guess is to choose words whose images are coset representatives of this stabilizer. That is, words for which the image of $n$ is $i$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

For example, we could choose words $$g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n = s_n, s_n^{-1},s_n^{-1}s_3,\ldots,s_n^{-1}s_{n-1}.$$ (I compose permutations from left to right.)

Now we have to prove that, for any coset rep $g_i$ and any generator $s_j$, we have $g_is_j \in \cup_{i=1}^n Hg_i.$

I am not going to do that in detail, but here are a few examples with $n=6$.

$s_6s_4 = s_4^{-1}s_6^{-1}$; $s_6^{-1}s_3s_4 = s_6^{-1}s_4^{-1}s_3^{-1} = s_4s_6s_3^{-1} = s_4s_6s_3ss_3 = s_4s_3^{-1}s_6^{-1}s_3$; $s_6^{-1}s_3s_6 = s_6s_3^{-1} = s_3^{-1}s_6^{-1}s_3$.

Comment: Can you explain how the map from g to an is surjective?Also cant we use the result that the alternating group is generated by 3 cycles.

Comment: The proof  that $A_n = \langle (1,2,3),(1,2,4),\ldots,(1,2,n)\rangle$ is a straightforward induction on $n$.